# Showing things one by one on screen in React/Redux

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Say I have the following in my React application in which my reducer holds the following state:

```
{
 array: ["Person 1", "Person 2", "Person 3"];
}
```

What I want to do is this. I want the user to press the space bar and `Person 1` is shown on the screen. I want the user then to press the space bar again, and to `Person 1` `Person 2` is added on the screen, and so on.

I have no idea how to do this, how I could control in Redux how many of the people on the list to show.

I am sorry for this very basic question, I am fairly new to React/Redux. I know how I could just go through the array and always show one person at a time, or all at once with a `map` function. But i am struggling with the idea of adding them gradually to the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, here's one:

```
export class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      players: [],
      currentPlayer: 0
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
      if (e.keyCode !== 32) return;
      this.setState({ currentPlayer: currentPlayer + 1 }) 
      // You should check beforehand if you are in the last index of your array, but I'll not do it here.
    });
  }
  // You need to remove the event Listener on willUnmount as well
  render() {
    if (!this.state.players.length)
      return <div> No Players </div>
    return (
      <div>{this.state.players[this.state.currentPlayer]}</div>
    )
  }
```

This is some basic structure, without redux. You can add redux later, but I suggest you learn the basics of React before jumping to Redux

Comment: Thank you! As I understand this code, it will always show me **one** current player. However, if I press space 3 times, I do not want to only show the 3rd player, but all player **up until the third**.

Comment: Yes, I missed that. You can refactor this code easily, changing `currentPlayer` to `currentPlayersIds` or something like that, and map over the players who are included in the `currentPlayerIds`